# How to get only html content containing no js code with document.body.innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```css
div#html,div#css,div#js,div#run{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    float:left;
}
div#content{
    clear:both;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
textarea{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='html'>html</div>
<div id='css'>css</div>
<div id='js'>js</div>
<div id='run'>run</div>
<div id='content'>
</div>
```

Now i want to get only the html content.

var  content=document.body.innerHTML;
alert(content)

The `alert` webpage will show html content adding my js code

[image]

How can get only html content containing no js code?

Why can't get it with str.replace?

```
var content=document.body.innerHTML;
var reg = new RegExp('<script type="text/javascript">.+</script>');
var onlyHtml = content.replace(reg,"");
alert(onlyHtml);
```

The whole html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type='text/css'>
    div#html,div#css,div#js,div#run{
        border:1px solid red;
        height:80px;
        width:80px;
        float:left;
    }
    div#content{
        clear:both;
        width:400px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    textarea{
        overflow:auto;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='html'>html</div>
    <div id='css'>css</div>
    <div id='js'>js</div>
    <div id='run'>run</div>
    <div id='content'>
    </div>        
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var content=document.body.innerHTML;
    var reg = new RegExp("<script type='text/javascript'>.+</script>");
    var onlyHtml = content.replace(reg,"");
    alert(onlyHtml);
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Why can't extract only html with regular expression?
Verify my regular expression:

```
var content = "<p>test</p><script type='text/javascript'>somany lines and \
              so many lines</script>"
var reg = new RegExp("<script type='text/javascript'>.+</script>");
var onlyHtml = content.replace(reg,"");
alert(onlyHtml);
```

It gets:

```
<p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerText` will return text data only.
So you can get the text data using `document.body.innerText`.

```js
const content = document.body.innerText;
alert(content);
```

```css
div#html,div#css,div#js,div#run{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    float:left;
}
div#content{
    clear:both;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
textarea{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='html'>html</div>
<div id='css'>css</div>
<div id='js'>js</div>
<div id='run'>run</div>
<div id='content'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clone the element and remove the script tags and whatever else you want.

```js
document.querySelector("button.show").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var bodyClone = document.querySelector('body').cloneNode(true);
  bodyClone.querySelectorAll('script, button.show').forEach(elem => elem.remove());
  console.log(bodyClone.innerHTML);  
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapperElem">
  <div id='html'>html</div>
  <div id='css'>css</div>
  <div id='js'>js</div>
  <div id='run'>run</div>
  <div id='content'>content</div>
  <button class="show">Show</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not revise my html structure and add new element in it.

Comment: Why can't extract only html with regular expression?

Comment: @showkey I added more than one and  the elements makes ZERO difference.

Comment: Why no reg exp? Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why to replace js code with regular expression can't work?

Comment: There is no need for reg exp..... Feel free to try....

Answer (score 0):

```
var content=document.body.innerHTML;
var reg = new RegExp('<script type="text/javascript">[^]+</script>');
var onlyHtml = content.replace(reg,"");
alert(onlyHtml);
```